# How to preload a fullscreen background video with a javascript preloader?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to [preload (PreLoadMe)](https://github.com/niklausgerber/PreLoadMe) a full-screen background video implemented with [BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/).
The preloader animation is working, but when the animation has finished, the background-video starts loading, which suggests that the content of the website has not been preloaded.

Unfortunately, my Javascript knowledge is very limited, so I would appreciate your input how to correctly load the video with the preloader.

Here is my **Javascript**:

```
<!-- Preloader -->

<script>
    $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    })
</script>


<!-- BigVideo -->

<script>

$(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
        BV.init();
if (Modernizr.touch) {
            BV.show('http://localhost/../img/background-dock.jpg');
        } else {
            BV.show('http://localhost/../vid/skiing.mp4', {altSource:'http://localhost/../vid/skiing.ogv', ambient:true});
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need a type/javascript or CDATA.

Comment: Code updated accordingly. Any suggestions how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, PreLoadMe doesn't really do anything.  All it does is show a loader until the browser fires the 'load' event.  Unfortunately, the browser fires that event when the page and images are loaded, it doesn't wait for BigVideo to load it's video.  A quick look at BigVideo doesn't reveal a way to hook into an event which will fire when the video actually begins to play.  If you can get access to the `player` object (which is an instance of Video.js), it may provide the event you need.

Comment: Just had a quick look at the [video.js documentation](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.3.0/docs/guides/api.md). Unfortunately, my Javascript knowledge is pretty limited. Any idea how to implement this?